# JSONB limitation: value too long for type character varying(255) Sequelize Error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have A JSONB field in my model that stores array objects. but these fields contain of html tags and texts. so this is a long character . but Im getting an error from sequelize .

> value too long for type character varying(255)

is there any limitation for this?I know I can use **Text** data Type . but this is not fixing my issue.

Comment: There should be no such limit on a jsonb column. Can you show your schema and code, please?

Comment: @Schwern this is my field options: DataTypes.JSON,